# GWT - How to add keyboardlistener to a canvas?

Tags: gwt, canvas

I'm trying to add keyboardlistener to a canvas in GWT. But it doesn't work.

I added also mouse handlers to this canvas and it works.

here is the mouse handler's code (this works):

```
    canvas.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {
        public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {     
            mouseX = event.getRelativeX(canvas.getElement());
            mouseY = event.getRelativeY(canvas.getElement());
        }
    });
```

here is the keyboard handler's code (this doesn't work):

```
    canvas.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            int key = event.getNativeKeyCode();
            System.out.println("key: " + (char) key);
            System.out.println("keypressed :"+ event.getNativeKeyCode());
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

---

**edit** : 
Initializing my canvas is done as the same way as this class : [GwtCanvasDemo.java](http://code.google.com/p/gwtcanvasdemo/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/gwtcanvasdemo/client/GwtCanvasDemo.java/). I just added addkeydownhandler and didn't work. I tried in Chrome and IE9.

Comment: Where are you initializing your `canvas`? Paste the code here.

Comment: And what browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this code. And its working for me.

```
RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

final Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
canvas.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
        int key = event.getNativeKeyCode();
        System.out.println("key: " + (char) key);
        System.out.println("keypressed :"+ event.getNativeKeyCode());
    }
});

rootPanel.add(canvas, 0 ,0);
```

Output: (when i pressed 'i','u','y' **after selecting the canvas on the browser**)

```
key: I
keypressed :73
key: U
keypressed :85
key: Y
keypressed :89
```

Comment: that didn't work for me. I select my canvas and my mouse handlers work but not the keyboards.

Comment: @tchike: What GWT SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using GWT 2.4.0. I replaced RootPanel by FocusPanel in which I added canvas and it worked.

Comment: Ok great! It was also working with RootPanel for me though. :)